# Load different css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have rails app with `active_admin`. `Active_admin` generator was generate `active_admin.css`. And on my pages(e.g `/projects`) I get mixed css files(my `style.css` and `active_admin.css`).
How I can separate load stylesheets files?

Comment: On what criteria do you want to include one, or the other, of the stylesheets? Server-side or client-side? Ruby, or JavaScript? Does the client choose which they want to see, or does it depend on something else? As it stands, this question cannot be reasonably answered without a lot of guess-work on our part.

Comment: The client must see `style.css`. The question is that the `active_admin.css` did not interfere with the client-side app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript you can check whatever you want and include css you want

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

or you can try like this in ruby..

the example is in php

http://snipplr.com/view/63586/wpconditional-css-files-loading/